# Is using weak references in Observers a good idea?

Tags: observer-pattern, weak-references, observable

I have implemented an Observable class that stores a list all the observers. Should this list contain weak references to the observers for preventing memory leaks?

What is common practise?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, it depends on the context. Some observers may just want to do simple things like logging and such, and would prefer to be kept alive by the Observable object. Best thing to do is just to clearly document your choice, so that observers know whether or not they need to explicitly deregister themselves.

Comment: Ok thx.. in my case Im not really interested to keep the objects alive, but I could do this if i call removeObserver before I know that all references are gone. If I forget it though, that object will be kept alive. What is the best design? Should the programmer need to keep track of that or is using weak references the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Off topic, if you are using Rx and not just the `IObservable` interface from .NET 4, you should map the `Subscribe` calls through to a private instance of `Subject` as it will handle thread safety and call order for you. You can then call `On*` on the subject instance.

On topic, it's typical that subscribers manage their own subscription. In the least this means disposing the `Subscribe` return value, but in Rx then subscription will usually be terminated by another operator (such as `Take` or `TakeUntil`).